# What happened to Rukia?

Tags: bleach

It's been a long time since I watched Bleach, but what ever happened to Rukia? Is it true that she vanished or something like that?

Answer (score 4):

The last time she appeared was at **manga chapter 604 - REVITALIZE** (until now).

As the manga is still ongoing (currently it is at **chapter 608**), she will keep on appearing at the following chapters.

You heard she vanished because of the **final episode of Fake Karakura Town arc: episode 342    "Thank You"**. Where Ichigo loses his shinigami's power, so he lost the ability to see her in shinigami form, so she "vanishes" from Ichigo's sight.

From [this wiki](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Rukia_Kuchiki), this is the moment where she "vanish":

> As it becomes harder for Ichigo to see her, Rukia knows this is
>   farewell. Mocking Ichigo's sad face, she states she will still be able
>   to see him, much to his displeasure. Rukia, disappearing from Ichigo's
>   sight completely, leaves through a Senkaimon as Ichigo, bidding
>   farewell, thanks her.

Answer (score 1):

No idea where you got the idea that she vanished.

Recent manga certainly feature her, up and fighting.

You say you haven't watched Bleach for a while - it has been off the air for a long time now. No idea when it will come back, if at all.

Comment: Its just that i read on wiki that she dissapeared from ichigo's sight or something like that